# Adding a cluster to OpsCenter via REST API adds cluster with no nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'm attempting to register a Cassandra 2.0.5.22 cluster (of 1 node for testing) to an OpsCenter 4.1.0 instance via opscenter's REST API. I can make the call using curl (I'm using Chef's http_request resource for our actual use case) with:

```
$ curl http://192.168.33.100:8888/cluster-configs -X POST -d \
  '{"jmx": {"port": "7199"}, 
    "cassandra": { 
        "username": "cassandra", 
        "seed_hosts": "10.0.2.15",
        "password": "cassandra"}}'
```

This successfully creates a cluster in opscenter (it's in the log), but the web UI will display "0 nodes" and "0 out 0 agents connected" in that cluster's view. If I create a second (or third) cluster with exactly the same call, that cluster will also be created but with knowledge of the single node. In the opscenter log, the node is recognized, and keyspace information transfered for each cluster, but it only appears in the web UI of secondary clusters. What is going on?

Comment: Can you exapdn on "no knowledge of any nodes"?  Does it simply say "0 nodes" in the UI?  Are there any connection errors in the log?  Adding multiple clusters using the same seed_hosts value is almost certainly going to cause wonkiness, so I'd recommend removing those for now, so we can more easily troubleshoot the core problem

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant that it says "0 nodes" and "0 out 0 agents connected" in the web UI.

Comment: Anything obviously wrong in the logs in terms of opscenterd trying to connect to cassandra?  You're specifying a username and password, so I assume you have authentication turned on on the c* side?  Lastly, have you tried entering the same values when adding a cluster in the UI, to see if the issue is related strictly to the API?